# finding Frequency inside the object Collections in java

Tags: java, list, collections

I know about the

```
Collections.frequency(obj1,obj2);
```

gives me  the number of times an object obj2 exists in collection obj1.
but i want to ask say obj1 is a collection(List) consisting of objects(student).

and a student can have {name,marks}

then is there any possible **Single or 2 lines** way through which i can find the number of students who have scored the same marks

I don't want any extra libraries to be included

Comment: When you say 'number of students who have scored the same marks', do you mean you want the number of students who have all scored a particular mark? Or the number of students who have scored non-unique marks? Or a list of frequencies for the different marks? Or what?

Comment: Your question sounds like it could be a prelude to a rant (note that I do not want to imply it is) about how complicated Java is. "I want to do something that is probably not common enough to have its own 10-lines Collections framework method, I want to do it in two lines and I do not want it to be done by any other library." Well, it's "pick any two" then, I guess.

Comment: @chm052.. number of students who have all scored a particular mark

Comment: @arne.b  what i meant is that 
1)---i want the answer to be simple enough so that it should not look like a rocket science solution. because the above question can be solved in many ways but what i asked for is the simplest solution(if any possible)

2) Since the project i am working on does not allow me to add extra libraries.

3) we have a solution but i found that was not very best solution that's why i asked this question. 
i hope i am able to explain the reason for my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collection.frequency`  returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object. It basically equaling obj2 with List objects.

If you override the `equals`  method and put your logic like based on score attribute Object will be equals or not. Then `Collection.frequency` return your desired result.

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private int score;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
         if(obj == null)
           return false;
         else if(this==obj)
           return true;
         else 
           return this.hashCode() == ((Student)obj).hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         return score;
   }
}
```

...

```
int freq = Collections.frequency(listOfStudent,student);
```

Comment: My apprehensions 
1) if i have to override equals method then i will have to override  hashCode method also(effective java).
2) In the above question's context if   i override the equals method then what i am saying is  that if the marks of two students are  equal then  they are also equal :O. i hope u  understood my apprehensions.

Comment: yap it is recommended because it is used in `HashMap`, `HashSet` where  ever this hashing is used it use [Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you're reluctant to alter your `equals` method to mean same scores == same student, you can use a Map to achieve what you want I think.  You have to do a little more setup, but retrieval should be 1 or 2 lines:

```
// setup/population
Map<Score, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<Score, List<Student>>();
for (Student student : students) {
  List<Student> studentsForScore = new ArrayList<Student>();
  if(map.containsKey(student.getScore())) {
    studentsForScore = map.get(student.getScore());
  }
  studentsForScore.add(student);
  map.put(student.getScore(), studentsForScore);
}

// information retrieval
Student testStudent = ...
int numberOfStudentsWithSameScore = map.containsKey(testStudent.getScore()) ? map.get(testStudent.getScore()).size() : 0;
```

This assumes of course that you're willing to accept the cost of the setup block.

What would be nice would be able to pass in a `Comparator` (or equivalent) into the `Collections.frequency` method - if you could you could get the best of both worlds.  As you cant, you could wrap the above code into your own `frequency` method

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Map instead of List

Comment: i guess you did not understood my question...kindly first look at frequency of Collections(java)

Answer (score 0):

You could `addAll` the students' marks to a `Set` of marks, and then compare if the size of the set is less than the size of your original `List` / `Map`.